# JQuery UI Autocomplete function modifying textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a textbox with an autocomplete function:

```
 $( "#mytextbox" ).autocomplete({
            source: bigData,
                        
            select: function(event, ui) {
                            
            $("#mytextbox").val(set this value here);
                        
            }
   });
```

As you can see, when an option is selected I want the textbox to actually change the value! I know that sounds crazy and stupid, but the automplete options give a detailed list with lots of info for each option, but I don't want all the data to be input, I just need a small segment of the data. For example if it was cities it might have:

> Birmingham, USA, Zip code...
>
> Birmingham, UK, post code...
>
> Birmingham, somewhere else,...

I want to be able to choose the correct "Birmingham", but I don't want all the other info input. What different does it make which one I choose then? Well other information is input in different boxes so the correct city is important.

So how can I modify the autocomplete function's assigned textbox inside the function? Is it possible?

Comment: Am I getting this right? You want the text in the autocomplete-text to be only 'Birmingham' but the data that's gonna be submitted should be 'Birmingham, UK, Post Code'?

Comment: The user chooses "Birmingham, UK..." out of the various options. But the form will submit whatever is in the textbox. I only need "Birmingham" in this textbox. SO I want to select "Birmingham, UK" and then the autocomplete function will change this to just "Birmingham.

Answer (score 0):

According to the jquery-ui docs the `ui` object contains an `item` object which is the selected item from the autocomple drop down. So if your items are listed the way you described it, i.e. `Birmingham, UK, 15780` you could simply split the string up by the comma and only use the first part to substitute the textbox value.

```
$( "#mytextbox" ).autocomplete({
        source: bigData,

        select: function(event, ui) {
          // not sure if ui.item is the text value itself
          // or an HTML item, gotta check that. I'm assuming a string here.
          var str = ui.item.split(",")[0];

          $("#mytextbox").val(str);
        }
});
```

Of course you can extend that by trimming whitespace, etc. This depends on the way you get your data...